# how do I extract with beautiful soup a nested span class value?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am struggling trying to figure out what is the element I need to tell Beautiful Soup to **scrape** the tag 'amount' value, which in this code sample is "1,56".

I am pasting below a code excerpt of the webpage I want to scrape:

```
<td class="line-content">
      <span class="html-tag">
       &lt;div
       <span class="html-attribute-name">
        class
       </span>
       ='
       <span class="html-attribute-value">
        the-price
       </span>
       '
       <span class="html-attribute-name">
        style
       </span>
       ='
       <span class="html-attribute-value">
        margin-top:20px;
       </span>
       '&gt;
      </span>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="line-number" value="447">
     </td>
     <td class="line-content">
      <span class="html-tag">
       &lt;span
       <span class="html-attribute-name">
        class
       </span>
       ='
       <span class="html-attribute-value">
        currency
       </span>
       '&gt;
      </span>
      €
      <span class="html-tag">
       &lt;/span&gt;
      </span>
      <span class="html-tag">
       &lt;span
       <span class="html-attribute-name">
        class
       </span>
       ='
       <span class="html-attribute-value">
        amount
       </span>
       '&gt;
      </span>
      1,56
      <span class="html-tag">
       &lt;/span&gt;
      </span>
     </td>
    </tr>
```

would you kindly enlighten me?
I am really grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the amount for example like this (`data` is your HTML string):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

span_with_amount = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'span' and tag.get_text(strip=True) == 'amount')
value = span_with_amount.parent.find_next_sibling(text=True)
print(value.strip())
```

Prints:

```
1,56
```

---

First we will find `<span>` with the text "amount" and then we will find the text that is next to the parent of this `<span>`.